# Configure LDAP server to display a specific error to the client's console?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I run an LDAP server that some machines are incorrectly configured to query. I believe these are Windows machines that think I'm their ActiveDirectory server. Is there a way to publish some information in LDAP which would cause these clients to display an error on the console, such as "Please contact the helpdesk"?

Comment: When you say: "an error on the console", what do you have in mind?  If they are Windows clients, are you hoping for a pop up notification?

Comment: @HelpingHand I'm looking to be able to display text on the console in any way shape or form. A pop up notification would be an example.